# Firebug destroying session variables in Codeigniter application

Tags: php, codeigniter, firebug

Well I m having strange problem here. I have a codeigniter 2 web application which requires user login.

My session works perfectly when I jump from one page to another. But when I turn on Firebug and try to jump to another page, i m kicked back to login page.

This happens always everytime I turn firebug on, but works okay if its not turned on. I have no clue whats going around.

Why Codeigniter session is not working when Firebug is turned on?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

**Edit:**

I have two separate applications made with Codeigniter. Both have same issue.

P.S. I am facing this problem in my local machine, haven't checked in remote server.

Thanks,
Sabin

Comment: a bit confused, arent session stored in the serverside? i think firebug just includes its own set of js so that it can work

Comment: yes even I wonder why this is happening, session are stored in the serverside. And I havent checked this in remote server The problem i m facing is in the local machine

Comment: http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/222443/

Comment: your application uses several ajax resources?

Comment: @csotelo, yes I have several ajax resources used

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you have the session filtering by user agent that's the problem. firebug adds additional stuff which can cause CI to think your session has been hijacked.

if you have firebug on globally, you may notice some sites tell you to disable the plugin for their site(for example gmail) for that very reason.

Comment: That did the trick. Thanks! Just to clarify: to turn off the filtering, set $config['sess_match_useragent'] = FALSE; in the config.php file.

Answer (score 0):

Also, if the sessions are not setting try a couple different values in cookie_domain. Setting it to empty did the trick to me. It appears that codeigniter tries to fill in the value for you ($config['cookie_domain'] = "";)